# Javascript/Mongo: sort specification itself as a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, strategy-pattern

I want to set a sorting criteria itself as a variable. It doesn't seem to work. Please help.

What works: (code snippet from Meteor's Blaze tutorial)

```js
return TasksCollection.find(hideCompleted ? pendingOnlyFilter : userFilter, {
  sort: { createdAt: -1 },
}).fetch();
```

However, I need to implement sorting order itself as a variable like below but doesn't work:

```js
sortingOrder = '{ createdAt: -1 }';
return TasksCollection.find(hideCompleted ? pendingOnlyFilter : userFilter, {
  sort: sortingOrder,
}).fetch();
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: just remove the string single quotes from `sortingOrder = { createdAt: -1 }` object.

Comment: That's a string, not an object.

Comment: This is a **very** basic concept in javascript. How objects and arrays work are the core of data structure programming in javascript. I strongly suggest you learn about object literal. In addition to what others have mentioned you can also do `sortingOrder = {}; sortingOrder.createdAt = -1`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an **object**, and you are passing the **string**. Change your code like this:

```js
sortingOrder = { createdAt: -1 };
return TasksCollection.find(hideCompleted ? pendingOnlyFilter : userFilter, {
  sort: sortingOrder,
}).fetch();
```